# Storing a list of server names, IPs and usernames in the web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I need to be able to store a list of server names, their IPs, username and passwords.

I did think of doing the following in the appSettings

```
   <add key="ServerXyz" value="TestServer;172.26.0.1;Admin;myPassword">
```

This means I can add a new key and prefix it with the word Server and each property I need is separated by a semi-colon so I can use a SPLIT.

ie.

```
   <add key="ServerAbc" value="AnotherTestServer;172.26.0.22;Admin;myAlternatePassword">
```

Although this would work and is future proof i.e. prefixing the key with "Server" so I can add additional servers without modifying code, it just doesn't seem a great implementation.

Is there a better way?

I need to get a list of Servers and all there properties from code.

I don't want to use a database and the list needs to be updatable without having alter any physical source code.

I did look at implementing a ConfigurationSection but I couldn't figure out how I was able to do this successfully.

Comment: dig deeper into ConfigurationSection, it is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Do not use web config, just create an xml or json file as you want. Better enrypt all these data.

Comment: Since this is intended for web, consider the following; If a change in this configuration (your server stuff) requires an app domain recycle, leave it in the web.config. If it doesn't, place it in an external file and reference that file from the web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a file in disk, and reading it into the application on start-up and caching the data.

You could use a basic flat file, or XML, or JSON. I recommend XML because it is easier to read, and will deserialize straight into a nice neat object for you to cache.

This is neater than just putting them into the web.config and allows you to use line endings to separate them and adds a bit of flexibility on what you can do.

Really though, a database might have been a better option

Comment: Thanks, I implemented a flat file .